# MaterialTable materialUI Icons not showing using fuse

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, fuse, material-table

I have a project that uses MaterialTable from material-ui and the icons are not showing

In my page I have the following import

```
import MaterialTable, { Column } from 'material-table';
```

In my fuse.ts setup I have the following

```
const fuse = FuseBox.init({
  homeDir: "./src",
  output: "./dist/$name.js",
  useTypescriptCompiler: true,
  sourceMaps: true,
  plugins: [
    CopyPlugin({ useDefault: true, files: ["*.png", "*.jpg", "*.ico", "*.svg", "*.tiff", "*.jpeg"] })
  ]
});
```

I am already using @material-ui/icons in my project. I have tried deleting the cache and restarting but it doesn't work.

when my page loads all the icons are missing

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was missing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

It had nothing todo with fuse